# Microsoft File Checksum Integrity Verifier (fciv.exe) not working/error

Tags: windows, security, hashing

I'm attempting to hash every file on my C:\ drive with

`fciv.exe c:\ -r -md5 -xml hashes.xml`

The xml file does not initially exist, but after the command is entered, the xml file is created. The command takes about 5 minutes to complete, but at the end, there is nothing in the xml file. The only thing is creates is a large error file that contains numerous "access denied" and "this file is being used by another process" errors.

I am running the command as an administrator. I even tried enabling the `net user administrator` account to run it from, but still the same results.

I did a test on a single file and it works fine. It outputs an MD5 hash no problem.

So my question is, what am I doing wrong? How can I hash my entire C drive using an fciv command?

Comment: I wouldn’t attempt to do this, attempting to do this on the number of files that exists even on a fresh installation of Windows, would create an output that would be unmanageable.  What would you do with it exactly?  You can’t compare it a previous version since the output would not in the same order each time.  Besides DISM already verifies the integrity of your system files

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues preventing it from running as desired.

- C:\ root has restrictions on what can be run.
- A file in use, e.g. *fciv.exe* itself, is locked.

Also, *fciv* apparently does not write intermediate results to disk and then concatenate them, so on long operations, it may runs out of memory.

Workarounds:

1. To avoid files locked while in use, run *fciv* on an **unmounted** partition. You can do so either by booting from Windows PE, and running *fciv* on the actual HDD, or by making an image, e.g. with [Macrium Reflect Free](https://www.macrium.com/reflectfree), mounting the image (check *Enable access to restricted folders* and *make writable*). You should be doing this regularly anyway, to keep an image in case something breaks.
2. Get a checksum for one folder at a time. If there's not enough ram available for this 32-bit application, then run it on *subfolders*.
3. Wait! The command  below took about an hour to complete on one PC, creating ~7MB of XML output!

   C:\temp>fciv.exe "c:\Program Files" -r md5 -xml out.xml